# Move element up using CSS only

Tags: css

I am creating a print stylesheet for an calendar element (based on fullcalendar.io).  The calendar is displayed with 15 minute timeslots on the y axis.  The print stylesheet does 2 things:

1. Removes the first 8 hours of the day (which is 32 rows of 15 mins per row)
2. Resizes the 15 min slots from 20px to 12px

The events that are rendered on the calendar are absolutely positioned and as such when this css resizing happens are out of place.  For example:

An event that started at 9am would have been positioned on the 37th row of the table, with top of `36*20 = 720px.`

The new position would need to take into account the missing first 32 rows `(32*20=640)` and then the fact that the remaining rows are 40% smaller (1-12/20).

I can transform the position using translateY however I cannot seem to make this work using both a fixed value and a % of the current top position in order to create a generic rule for each event.  Is this possible using just CSS?

**Edit**

I'm not sure how to demonstrate with a code snippet,however it really comes down to one simple issue:  I need to move an absolutely positioned element up by 40% of it's current top value.

If the element has `top: 100px`

I need it to be positioned at 60px

If it has `top: 250px`

I need it to be positioned at 150px

The calculation is easy but I don't seem to be able to use the current top value in CSS

Comment: can you make a simple example that replicates your problem ? ( code ). Otherwise its hard for us to help you

Answer (score 1):

WIthout any code that might help me understand what exactly the problem is, i understand that you want to move up an element with a fixed value (px) and a `%` value.

You can do this in 2 ways.

1. Use `calc(px +/- %)` in `translateY`
2. Use `margin-top:-npx` together with `translateY(-%)`

See below example with option 1

```css
.top {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
}

.move-me {
  transition: 0.3s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

section:hover .move-me {
  transform: translateY(calc(-50px - 50%))
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="top">

  </div>
  <div class="move-me">

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This is exactly the lines I have been trying - the issue I am having is that the % value in the calc seems to refer to the elements height, and not its top position which is what needs to change.  I can easily subtract a fixed value using margin-top or translateY, the part I am struggling with is then reducing the remaining top value by 40%

Comment: @Marcos. Yes the percentage inside the translateX or Y reffers to the elements height/width. `reducing the remaining top value by 40%` Can you elaborate on that ? remaining top value of which element ? and relative to what position? In short, please explain what is that `40%` ? it's very hard to understand without any example code

Comment: I have added a clarification in the question - does it make sense now?

Comment: @Macros Yes. So you want to move the element up with 40% of it's current position. It's not possible with only CSS if you don't know it's exact current position. With javascript/jquery would be possible